# does anyone know what this warning means?

Tags: flutter, just-audio

Does anyone know what this warning (not an error/exception) means?

```
W/MetadataUtil( 7942): Failed to parse standard genre code
```

Some audio files triggers this warning and no audio comes out for that particular file.

just_aduio thinks its playing as the positionStream and playingStream shows progression, but with no sound. Other files work without any problem.

This is related [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74840235/some-files-do-not-play) I asked earlier. However I did not get much help (I do realize my question was lacking a lot of imformation) so in this post **I just want to know what this error means**.